# variables not showing in string when I post?

Tags: php, html

This  is the HTML Page for my mad lib form where I have a form to fill out a mad lib. Once the user fills out the form he will submit and it should return with the completed mad lib.

```
<head>

    <title>This page sends the data</title>

</head>

    <body>
        <em><h1>Hip-Hop Mad Libs</h1></em>

        <form action="page2.php" method="post">
            <!--1-->
            <label for="clothing">Item of clothing:</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="clothing" id="clothing">


            <br><br>
            <!--2-->
            <label for="adj1">Adjective:</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="adj1" id="adj1">


            <br><br>
            <!--3-->
            <label for="verb1">-ing Verb</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="verb1" id="verb1">


            <br><br>
            <!--4-->
            <label for="verb2">-ed Verb</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="verb2" id="verb2">


            <br><br>
            <!--5-->
            <label for="nickname">Nickname:</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname">

            <br><br>

            <!--6-->
            <label for="race">Race of people:</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="race" id="race">


            <br><br>
            <!--7-->
            <label for="valued">Thing OF Value:</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="valued" id="valued">


            <br><br>
            <!--8-->
            <label for="body">Body Function:</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="body" id="body">


            <br><br>
            <!--9-->
            <label for="verb3">-ed Verb:</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="verb3" id="verb3">


            <br><br>
            <!--10-->
            <label for="woman">Famous Woman:</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="woman" id="woman">


            <br><br>

            <!--11-->
            <label for="occupation">Odd Occupation:</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="occupation" id="occupation">


            <br><br>

            <!--12-->
            <label for="occupation2">Same Occupation:</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="occupation2" id="occupation2">


            <br><br>
            <!--13-->
            <label for="body2">Body Part:</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="body2" id="body2">


            <br><br>
            <!--14-->
            <label for="behavior">Behavior:</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="behavior" id="behavior">


            <br><br>
            <!--15-->
            <label for="nickname2">Mean Nickname:</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="nickname2" id="nickname2">


            <br><br>
            <!--16-->
            <label for="verb4">-ed Verb:</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="verb4" id="verb4">


            <br><br>
            <!--17-->
            <label for="body3">Body Part:</label><br>

            <input type="text" name="body3" id="body3">


            <br><br>



            <button type="submit">Submit</button>

        </form>
        <img src="madlib.jpg" style= "width: 600px;heigth:600px" >

</body>
```

Here is the PHP where the variables are posted to create the mad lib but when I click submit on the form it only shows the paragraph without the variables

```
<?php
            $clothing = $_GET["clothing"];
            $adj1 = $_GET["adj1"];
            $verb1 = $_GET["verb1"];
            $verb2 = $_GET["verb2"];
            $nickname = $_GET["nickname"];
            $race = $_GET["race"];
            $valued = $_GET["valued"];
            $body = $_GET["body"];
            $verb3 = $_GET["verb3"];
            $woman = $_GET["woman"];
            $occupation = $_GET["occupation"];
            $occupation2 = $_GET["occupation2"];
            $body2 = $_GET["body2"];
            $behavior = $_GET["behavior"];
            $nickname2 = $_GET["nickname2"];
            $verb4 = $_GET["verb4"];
            $body3 = $_GET["body3"];


            $message= "Once upon a time not long ago, where people wore $clothing and
       lived life slow, when were $adj1 and justice stood, and people were $verb1 like they ought ta good. There lived a little boy who was $verb2 by another little boy and this is what he said: Me and you,$nickname we're gonna make  some cash, robbing $race and making a dash.They did the job, $value came with ease. But one couldn't $body. It's like he had a disease. He $verb3 another and another and $woman and her brother;tried to rob a man who a/am $occupation. The $occupation2 grabbed his $body2 he started acting $behavior.He said, Keep still, $nickname2, no need for static, $verb4 him in his $body3 and he gave him a slap.";


        echo $message;              
        ?>
```

Comment: user $_REQUEST instead of $_GET..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` variable in your PHP code.

```
$clothing = $_POST["clothing"];
$adj1 = $_POST["adj1"];
$verb1 = $_POST["verb1"];
$verb2 = $_POST["verb2"];
...
```

You use `$_GET` variable only when your form has no method set or is set to get `<form method="get">`. You usually use `$_GET` variables if you are dealing with query strings. That is the texts that you see in the URLs after the domain. e.g. http://google.com/search?query_sting=value.

If you don't want the data to be exposed in the url after submit, use `<form method="post">` and access data in PHP using `$name=$_POST['name']`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `POST` as form's method and trying to access using [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), you need to access the values using [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), so change to

```
$clothing = $_POST["clothing"];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In order you code to work

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
```

must be changed to:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="get">
```

or in your **PHP** use the **$_POST** variable:

```
 $clothing = $_POST["clothing"];
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using post method so you should use code.

```
<?php
            $clothing = $_POST["clothing"];
            $adj1 = $_POST["adj1"];
            $verb1 = $_POST["verb1"];
            $verb2 = $_POST["verb2"];
            $nickname = $_POST["nickname"];
            $race = $_POST["race"];
            $valued = $_POST["valued"];
            $body = $_POST["body"];
            $verb3 = $_POST["verb3"];
            $woman = $_POST["woman"];
            $occupation = $_POST["occupation"];
            $occupation2 = $_POST["occupation2"];
            $body2 = $_POST["body2"];
            $behavior = $_POST["behavior"];
            $nickname2 =$_POST["nickname2"];
            $verb4 = $_POST["verb4"];
            $body3 = $_POST["body3"];


            $message= "Once upon a time not long ago, where people wore $clothing and
       lived life slow, when were $adj1 and justice stood, and people were $verb1 like they ought ta good. There lived a little boy who was $verb2 by another little boy and this is what he said: Me and you,$nickname we're gonna make  some cash, robbing $race and making a dash.They did the job, $value came with ease. But one couldn't $body. It's like he had a disease. He $verb3 another and another and $woman and her brother;tried to rob a man who a/am $occupation. The $occupation2 grabbed his $body2 he started acting $behavior.He said, Keep still, $nickname2, no need for static, $verb4 him in his $body3 and he gave him a slap.";


        echo $message;              
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to choose, I would probably not use `$_REQUEST`, and I would choose `$_GET` or `$_POST` -- depending on what my application should do `(i.e. one or the other, but not both)` : generally speaking :

- You should use `$_GET` when someone is requesting data from your application.
- And you should use `$_POST` when someone is pushing (inserting or updating ; or deleting) data to your application.

**So, just change in your code :**

```
<form action="page2.php" method="get">
```

Answer (score 0):

> you are submitting the form using POST method and getting the value
>   with GET method.you should GET for both or POST for both..